# Meaning of Lyric No Love Allowed by Rihanna

Tags: meaning

I read the lyric of Rihanna song, No Love Allowed.
But here's, I don't understand about the meaning of this part

> **Fe fo fum** like the sky is falling down on me Numb numb numb, he's so
>   cold he doesn't feel a thing Broken heart was the case Gwan and put
>   'im away He's the only one one one I ever let get the best of me

What is **Fe fo fum** mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems most likely to be an abridged quotation of *Fee-fi-fo-fum*, the opening line of the giant's rhyme in the tale of [Jack and the Beanstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_the_Beanstalk):

**Fee-fi-fo-fum**!

I smell the blood of an Englishman,

Be he alive, or be he dead,

I'll grind his bones to make my bread.

The phrase seems like nonsense to the modern reader, and though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee-fi-fo-fum puts forward some theories as to possible historical meanings of the words, the rhyme is also reported to be already old and obscure by 1596.

As well as rhyming with 'numb', the themes of doom and destruction in the rhyme are echoed in Rihanna's song.

Answer (score 3):

It's a nonsense lyric based on a rhyme from an old children's story, [Jack and the Beanstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee-fi-fo-fum).  Some researchers believe the children's rhyme may be a corruption of a phrase in ancient Gaelic, but that has nothing to do with the song, where it's just used for its sound (similar to syllables like "la la la" or "na na na").